# JFileChooser returns not all path

Tags: java, directory, jfilechooser

using following method on Path button click:

```
public static void pathButtonAction() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    if (pathToInbound == null) { //private static File pathToInbound;
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    } else {chooser.setCurrentDirectory(pathToInbound);
            }

    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose folder with messages to send");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        pathToInbound = chooser.getCurrentDirectory(); 
        addLogText(chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    }


}
```

But here i choose folder c:\windows\temp
Here addLogText(chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) i get to log only c:\windows. Why temp folder was ignored/truncated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `chooser.getSelectedFile()` instead of `chooser.getCurrentDirectory()`, this returns the current directory where the user has navigated in the filechooser. In your case it is `C:\Windows`.